# react-router-redux - syncHistoryWithStore seems to be missing

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I downloaded a react router and redux tutorial (from https://learnredux.com/ if you know this) and played with it. I want to copy my code into the standard app from facebook (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html). Although I installed all of the dependencies I don't get it to work.

Trying a lot of `console.log()`I could figure out that syncHistoryWithStore gives me an `undefined`.

I am quite new to npm and stuff like this, coming from plain html. Is there a smart way to track my problem, check my missing dependencies or whatever it takes to solve a problem like this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: a lot has changed.. maybe you want to follow the react router docs as a guide. once you get that setup you can try getting redux up and running https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/redux-integration

Comment: Thanks. This is a lot to process. I think I will have to wait for another tutorial :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going through the same tutorial. When I used:

```
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
```

Instead of:

```
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router';
```

It started working. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and it seemed to help but I had to change A LOT of other stuff too. Now react seems to have a problem with this line of code `export const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);`